# computer science

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


struct dateofbirth{
    char day[2];
    char month[2];
    char year[4];
};

struct address{
    char city[20];
    char address[20];
};

struct Student{
    char Fname[20];
    char Lname[20];
    char ID[10];
    char email[20];
    char gpa[5];
    struct dateofbirth;
    struct address;
};

int check (student x[],int n,char key[],char key2[]){
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(x[i].ID,key[])==0 && strcmp(x[i].Pass,key2[])==0)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
};

int main() {
    char ID[10];
    char Pass[10];
    char x;
    int res;

    cout << "If you are a student please press ' S ' "<< endl
         << "If you are an  admain pleass press ' A ' "<< endl;

    cin>> x;  
    if (x == 's' || x == 'S') {
        cout<<"Enter your ID "; 
        cin>>ID;   
        cout<<"Enter your password ";
        cin>>Pass;
        res=check(list,n,ID,Pass);
    }  
    else {
        cout<<"error";
    }
}
return 0;
```

what is this error mean ???

||=== Build: Release in try (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
E:\try\main.cpp|26|error: 'student' was not declared in this scope|
E:\try\main.cpp|26|error: expected primary-expression before 'int'|
E:\try\main.cpp|26|error: expected primary-expression before 'char'|
E:\try\main.cpp|26|error: expected primary-expression before 'char'|
E:\try\main.cpp|26|error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]|
E:\try\main.cpp|26|error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token|
||=== Build failed: 6 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: The compiler does not know what "student" is in the following expression "int check (student x[],int n,char key[],char key2[])". A few lines before that a struct called Student is declared (hint). BW: I guess this has nothing to do with Arduino so you might be on the wrong forum.

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with *computer science*. Please [edit] your question to a) include a title that clearly explains the problem you're having or question you're asking; b) includes a tag for the language you're coding in; and c) clearly explains the problem you're having with the code you dumped and asks a specific question about that code. If you need help doing so, read [ask] and then learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Downvote for stupid title, and it doesn't have anything to do with [tag:compiler-construction] either.

Answer (score 0):

> E:\try\main.cpp|26|error: 'student' was not declared in this scope|

It means just what it says: you refer to `student` on line 26 as though it were a type, and it's not.  There is a struct `Student`, but that's not the same thing.  C++ is case sensitive.

Per the comments, you should edit your question to be tagged C++.